# how to install adobe reader silent without gui and opening browser

Tags: batch-file, adobe, wget, command-prompt, adobe-reader

I'm making a autoinstall batch program, and I want to install adobe reader silent. The problem is that it won't install silent. I'm getting the gui asking me to click next and wait. After it is installed it will open the browser. Is there anything so I can install Adobe Reader silent and without opening the browser.

This is the batch code:

```
@ECHO OFF
cd /d "%~dp0"
wget http://aihdownload.adobe.com/bin/install_reader11_nl_mssd_aih.exe -O Reader.exe
Reader.exe /S /norestart ALLUSERS=1 EULA_ACCEPT=YES
```

I've also tried this:

```
@ECHO OFF
wget http://aihdownload.adobe.com/bin/install_reader11_nl_mssd_aih.exe -O Reader.exe
start /wait Reader.exe /s
```

I couldn't find a fix for the browser. Hope this code helps a bit.
I could use msi files but I can't find where to download it. Here is the ftp from adobe for the exe file:

Ftp: ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/win/11.x/11.0.09/en_US/

Exe: ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/win/11.x/11.0.09/en_US/AdbeRdr11009_en_US.exe

Comment: Take a look on [IT Pro Tips for Adobe Reader 11](http://www.itninja.com/software/adobe/reader-6/11-1657). There are thousands of other pages found by WWW search engines using **adobe reader silent install** as keywords.

Comment: I looked through a dozen of sites, but nothing works. I'll will read your link later cause I have to go now. I'll tell you later if it worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases .msi switches **"/quiet /passive /norestart"** will do the trick

To help you take it further here is **Adobe Reader XI 11.0.07 full, Switchless install**
- completely silent!!
- no desktop icon
- checked on win 7 (x64x86)

The silent installer can be used in any Windows version that is compatible with the originals setup.

Created by "ugi" from wincert.net.

A nifty tool that can determine the switches of most installers automatically for you can be downloaded from here...**[Universal-Silent-Switch-Finder](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/Launchers-Shutdown-Tools/Universal-Silent-Switch-Finder.shtml)**

And if you would like this tool in a "send to" add on, visit wincert.net and do a search in the add-on's section of the forum.

Hope my post makes your batch endeavors easier :)
L8r

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping. I've find out that this is the code I need. Thanks for your help Mofi

```
wget ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/win/11.x/11.0.00/en_US/AdbeRdr11000_en_US.msi -O Reader.msi
msiexec.exe /I Reader.msi /QN
```

I'll will mark it answered as soon as I can

Answer (score 0):

The best solutions is to create mst file that will:

Disable product updates
Disable Help
Disable Product Improvement Program
Disable Viewing of PDF with Ads for Adobe PDF
Disable all Adobe online services based workflows and entry points

And after that download msi file and run the following command from batch:

```
@echo silent install Adobe Reader 11.0.10

start /wait msiexec /i "%~dp0AcroRead.msi" TRANSFORMS="AcroRead.mst" /Update "%~dp0AdbeRdrUpd11010.msp" /qn
```

To create mst file is not very easy. You can learn from google or from [here](http://www.get-itsolutions.com/silent-install-adobe-reader-11-0-10-and-disable-update/).

Answer (score 0):

Using PowerShell and the Adobe Reader .exe:

```
Start-Process "C:\TEMP\AcroRdrDC2300820421_en_US.exe" -ArgumentList "/sPB /rs /msi"
```